# SQLite error when clearing all rows in the table?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public class SQLiteTestActivity extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MP_DB.db";
private static final String MP_TABLE_NAME = "MPDetails";

SQLiteTestActivity (Context context) { 
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}// end of 

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + MP_TABLE_NAME + " ( " +
            BaseColumns._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            " name TEXT, " +
            " lat REAL, "+
            " lng REAL,"+
            " roll REAL,"+
            " pitch REAL,"+
            " yaw REAL,"+
            " path TEXT"+
            ");" );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


public String getMP_Name(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteCursor c = (SQLiteCursor) db.rawQuery("SELECT name FROM MP_Data WHERE "+
                                                BaseColumns._ID+" = "+
                                                Long.toString(id), null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    String r = c.getString(0);
    return r;       
}

public Double getMP_Lat(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteCursor c = (SQLiteCursor) db.rawQuery("SELECT lat FROM MP_Data WHERE "+
                                                BaseColumns._ID+" = "+
                                                Long.toString(id), null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    Double r = c.getDouble(0);
    return r;       
}

public int getRowsCounter() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    SQLiteCursor c = (SQLiteCursor) db.rawQuery("SELECT COUNT (*) FROM MPDetails ", null);
    c.moveToFirst();
    int r = c.getCount();
    return r;       
}

public void deleteMP(long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(MP_TABLE_NAME, BaseColumns._ID+"="+Long.toString(id),null);   
}

public void deleteALLMP() {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(MP_TABLE_NAME,null, null);    
}
```

}

```
OnClickListener save_btnListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db =  mphelper.getWritableDatabase();
        cv = new ContentValues();

        String str1 = et01.getText().toString();
        String str2 = et02.getText().toString();

        if( (("").equals(str1) ||("").equals(str2))) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "both or either fields are empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else{

        cv.put("name", str1);
        cv.put("lat", Double.valueOf(str2));


        long newID = db.insert("MPDetails", null, cv);
        count = mphelper.getRowsCounter();

        if (newID != -1){
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                          "data saved ", 
                           Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();              
        }// end if
        }txt04.setText(String.valueOf(count));      
    }
};
```

OnClickListener clear_btnListener = new OnClickListener() {

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        txt04 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt04);
        mphelper.deleteALLMP();
        count = mphelper.getRowsCounter();
        txt04.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    }
};
```

1-When I clear the DB with the "clear_btnListener" and the click save "save_btnListener"
the application crashes despite I wrote if statement to check whthere the fields to be save are empty or not.

2-when I clear the DB and display number of rows in the table, I expect to get zero but actually, I get 1 ???

Comment: please add logcat output or specify the error in logcat

Answer (score 1):

You should delete your existing MP_DB.db on your emulator/phone.
and recreate the database having the following changed
in SQLiteTestActivity:

```
private static final String MP_TABLE_NAME = "MPDetails";
```

to

```
private static final String MP_TABLE_NAME = "MP_Data";
```

and in SQLSaveData:

```
long newID = db.insert("MPDetails", null, cv);
```

to

```
long newID = db.insert("MP_Data", null, cv);
```

and set the following

```
et02.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_SIGNED);
```

otherwise you will get NumberFormatException

---

Cheers

Comment: set it as an answer then please

Answer (score 0):

AS far as i could say...all sqlite realated stuff u better do it on SqliteActivity and make an object of that class and use it.